# how to handle huge volume of data transfer in gwt?

Tags: database, spring, gwt, google-chrome

I have to transfer a huge number of data from database to client side using gwt RPC.
the data gets fetched by the service but during mapping of bean it returns error.

Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
- **on terminal**

Something other than an int was returned from JSNI method '@com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader::readInt()': JS value of type Java Object com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JsValueOOPHM$DispatchObjectOOPHM, expected int - **on browser**

why might this happen?

Comment: Are you getting this error only in dev mode ? Which browser are you using ?

Comment: yeah. I am using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug in Chrome when using dev mode. It's been there for a while. It is tracked [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5778). The only workaround for now is to use Firefox instead of Chrome.